# Mouse scroll and additional buttons

Tags: wireless, mouse

I've just installed ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop after using it a while in a virtual machine, and I got this annoying problem > mouse scroll TOOOOOO fast (vertical) and TOOOOOO slow (horizontal). I'm using a Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000. Is there a way to configure scroll and the 2 side buttons of my mouse (the default actions for them are back and forward) ?

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to (in such manner it will give You all options possible)

```
xinput
```

command in Your terminal. It is used to do such things. For example:

```
xinput list
```

lists all devices conncted. Find mouse or Your mouse name. To see properties of Your mouse write:

```
xinput list-props YourMouseID
```

And from now on it is hard to tell what You can change there, because my mouse is not the type You have. However this is possibly the best way to configure Your mouse using

```
xinput set-<some>-prop
```

PS.: remember to be careful and to become SU to have the permission to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Solution mentioned here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1696794

> Some MS mice have a scrollwheel bug. Try unplugging (wait a few
>   seconds) then replugging usb cable. If that fixes the scroll speed
>   then your mouse has this bug. There is no permanent fix that I could
>   find except to buy a none-MS mouse.
>
> Good Luck.

Worked for me and others on this site. Although clicking the mouse button *still* does nothing.